# Angular invalidates JWT for no obvious reason (Angular+Laravel API)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, jwt

I'm building an app with AngularJS + Laravel 5 that uses JWT as authentication. The problem is that after logging into the app, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

I'm inclined to think that this is more on the angular side since testing the API with Postman never fails, I copy and paste the token into the headers and everything runs smoothly.

When navigating via Chrome, just after logging in i receive the token in the request headers, save it with angular in localStorage and the next request sends the new token, but the server responds with `{error: "token_invalid"}`

My token request is just as the angular docs say

```
`return $http({
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/api/authenticate',
        skipAuthorization: true,
        method: 'POST',
        data: { grant_type: 'refresh_token', refresh_token: refreshToken }
    }).then(function(response) {
        var jwt = response.headers().authorization;
        localStorage.setItem('jwt', jwt);
        return jwt;
    });`
```

With chrome XHRs I see the following
I log in to the app and get an XHR with the response header `Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eX...`
I make the second request, the app automatically sends `Authorization:Bearer Bearer eyJ0eX...` as a Request Header

Note that `Bearer` gets duplicated for some reason but the Tymon/JWTAuth library for Laravel strips the Bearer method leaving only the token part (eyJ0eX...).
In fact, copying `Bearer Bearer eyJ0eX...` as a header in Postman works fine.
The real problem comes with the next request, I receive the new token `Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eX2...` but when sending it in the new request I get an 401 error, the token is invalid, sometimes it is expired instead of invalid.
Pasting `Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eX2...` in Postman also rejects the token but since it's a new one, it shouldn't.

What is angular/angular-jwt doing to invalidate a token that was just generated and hasn't been used yet?
And why sometimes it just works?

Comment: Do you guys have found the solution?

Comment: @Pablo Unfortunately no, I wasn't able to solve this issue and since I was pressured by the delivery date I explained to my client that the only way I'd be able to finish the project in time was to throw away angular and use only regular POST forms since I had much more experience in the conventional field.